# Node JS Instanciate classe A in classe B

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm beginning in node.js and I just want to use my class B into my class A, but it seems not work... Here's my very simple code, I guess I do something wrong...  I have 2 files (for 2 classes) :

**Poney.js :**

```
const {DeadPool} = require('./DeadPool');

class Poney {


  constructor() {
    this.regInter = setInterval(() => this.Regeneration(), 500);
    this.energy = 0;
    this.isUnicorn = false;
  }

  Regeneration() {
    this.energy += 10;
    console.log(`Regeneration, Vitalite : ${this.Vitalite}`);
    if (this.energy > 100) {
      console.log('Evolution');
    }
  }

  KillPoney() {
    clearInterval(this.RegInter);
  }

  evolve() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.isUnicorn = false) {
          console.log('pas une licorne');
          if(this.energy > 100) {
            resolve();
            this.energy = 0;
            this.isUnicorn = true;
            console.log('Transformation unicorn !');
          }
          else {
            console.log('Energie insuffisante');
            reject();
          }
        }
        else {
          reject();
          console.log('Already an unicorn');
        }
      }, 1000);
    });


  }


  backPoney() {                    //Retransforme les licornes en poney
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        if (this.isUnicorn = false) {
          resolve();
          this.energy = 0;
          console.log('Back Poney to Unicorn');
        }
        else {
          reject();
          console.log('Not an Unicorn');
        }


      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}

const myDeadpool = new DeadPool();



//setTimeout(() => MyPoney.killPoney(), 10000);

module.exports = {Poney};
```

**DeadPool.js :**

```
const {Poney} = require('./Poney');

class DeadPool {


  constructor() {

    this.regInterDead = setInterval(() => this.regeneration(), 4000 );
    this.transInter = setInterval(() => this.makeUnicorn(), 4000 );
    this.isRegenerate = false;
    this.poneys = [];
    for (var iVal = 0; iVal < 10; iVal++) {

      this.poneys.push(new Poney())
    }

  }
  makeUnicorn(){
    this.makeEvolve()
      .then(() =>  console.log('Evolve ok !'))
      .catch(() => console.log('error evolve'));
  }

  regeneration(){
    this.checkPoney()
      .then(() => console.log('Regeneration Deadpool'))
      .catch(() => console.log('Pas de regeneration'));
  }



  checkPoney() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        var iNumPoney = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var bConard = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1) >= 1);      // 1 chance sur 2 d'utiliser la licorne
        if (bConard){
          this.poneys[iNumPoney].backPoney()
            .then(() =>  console.log('Licorn to Poney ok'))
            .catch(() => console.log('back licorn rejected'));
          this.isRegenerate = true;
          resolve();
        }

        else{
          console.log('Je ne suis pas un conard');
          reject();
        }
      }, 1000);
    });
  }


  makeEvolve() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
        var iNumPoney = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
        var bGentil = (Math.floor((Math.random() * 1) + 1) > 1);      // 1 chance sur 2 de la faire evoluer
        if(bGentil) {
          poneys[iNumPoney].evolve()
            .then(() =>  console.log('TRANSFORMATION !'))
            .catch(() => console.log('Evolution impossible'));
          resolve();

        }
        else {
          console.log('Pas gentil');
          reject();
        }


      }, 1000);
    });


  }
}


module.exports = {DeadPool};
```

And I have an Error in the constructor of Poney when I'm trying to instanciate new Poney :

```
*"C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 2016.3.3\bin\runnerw.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" C:\Users\Stef\Desktop\Cours\JS\Poney.js
C:\Users\Stef\Desktop\Cours\JS\DeadPool.js:19
      this.poneys[iVal] = new Poney();
                          ^
TypeError: Poney is not a constructor
    at new DeadPool (C:\Users\Stef\Desktop\Cours\JS\DeadPool.js:19:27)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Stef\Desktop\Cours\JS\Poney.js:74:20)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:605:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:422:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:143:9)*
```

Thank you for your help..

Comment: Your requires are a circular reference. I would try to avoid that.
One file starts execution, and before it instantiates anything it goes off and tries to execute the other file. The other file then does the same. Neither have exports created yet so you just get nothing back from each other in the require results. (something like that)

Answer (score 1):

As I commented, your circular requires are causing an issue.

Try passing the Poney class into DeadPool while instantiating DeadPool.

1. Remove `const {Poney} = require('./Poney');` from DeadPool.
2. Change `const myDeadpool = new DeadPool();` to `const myDeadpool = new DeadPool(Poney);`
3. Change Deadpool constructor to take in Poney `constructor(Poney) {`

There are many ways you can do it, this is just a basic example.